# Html.ActionLink gives error: Cannot resolve action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using Html.ActionLink in my jquery But I am getting error when I type my Action Names, check my update.

Why am I getting this? I really need to to use ActionLink here.

Here is the jquery code:

```
result.forEach(function (goalcard) {
    $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").append(
            $('<tr/>', {
                click: function () {
                    id = goalcard.Id;
                    var url = '@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI", new { id = "__id__"})';
                    window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);


                },
                // steg Create a row for each result 
                html: "<td>" + goalcard.Name +
                "</td><td>" + goalcard.Customer +
                "</td><td>" + goalcard.PlannedDate +
                "</td><td>" + goalcard.CompletedDate + 
                "</td><td>" + '@(Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit","Admin")) | @(Html.ActionLink("Skapa Mall", "Inactive","Admin", new { @class = "deleteLink" })) | @(Html.ActionLink("Genomför","AnswerForm","AnswerNKI"))' + "</td>"
            }));
    });
    $('#GoalcardSearchResult tbody').trigger("update");
    $("#GoalcardSearchResult").tablesorter({
        headers: { 4: { sorter: false } }
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

Problem is found, my action methods have int ID as parameter. I need to do following:

```
@(Html.ActionLink("Genomför", "AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI", new {id = goalcard.id}, null))
```

goalcard.id carry the ID but in some strange way I am getting an new error:

Cannot resolve symbol "goalcard"

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is this: `new { id = "__id__"})'` ?

Comment: I was just testing around when i wrote that Ill remove it

Comment: Please, check the code before you publish your post.

Comment: Well I dont think that is causing the problem. Or is it?

Comment: BTW, is `forEach` a valid jQuery method?

Comment: What about this line: `@(Html.ActionLink("Ändra", "Edit","Admin")) | @(Html.ActionLink("Skapa Mall", "Inactive","Admin", new { @class = "deleteLink" })) | @(Html.ActionLink("Genomför","AnswerForm","AnswerNKI"))'` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to fill my column with three links that takes the user to another view with the Goalcard.ID

Comment: @RammtinAvar : did you try to use the <text></text> tags? This always helps because Razor sometimes fails when you mix JavaScript with your Razor syntax.

Comment: After testing I am getting an error that I need to add an ID beacuse the action method have ID as parameter

Comment: goalcard.id carry the ID of the goalcard. How can I use it inside my Html.ActionLink I have tried New {id = goalcard.id} but I recieve cannot resolve symbol "goalcard"

Answer (score -2):

Which of the links is the error coming from? Or is it all of them? I've found that using T4MVC removes a lot of problems surrounding magic strings like the ones you have in your JSON.

http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/

It might be worth copying the method signatures from your controller to help us answer the question.

The other possible problem might be that one of the controller actions has the [HttpPost] attribute.

Comment: Are you getting compile errors? If the controller hasn't built, you may be accidentally running an old version.